# Post request to Golang API to send JSON and stringy-fied JSON

Tags: json, go, post, gorilla, mux

While making a `POST` request to Golang API, if I send stringy-fied `JSON` data it returns success but when I send `JSON` data it returns error with `status 403`.

Please help me understanding this behavior and how can I send `JSON` data using a `POST` request method.

File: main.go

```
package main

import (
    "devmgmtv2/auth"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    auth.AuthInit(router)
    ssid.SsidInit(router)
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
    router.HandleFunc("/auth/login", Login).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(headersOk, originsOk, methodsOk)(router)))
}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Create User Struct
    var user User
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)
    userPassword := getUserPassword(user.User)
    // call get value for that user
    // check for equality if true, return the structure
    // if false return error
    if user.Password == userPassword {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        w.Write([]byte("success"))
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "It works when I pass my JSON in String format i.e. raw text but when it Send a JSON" mean? JSON is a text format and is send always as "string" or "text". What did you do _exactly_?

Comment: When I was sending data after Doing JSON.stringify(data) it worked, but when I was sending data as is . It wasn't working. But it used to work with NodeJS server

Comment: It sounds like your client-side code isn't producing JSON, then, and there's nothing wrong with your Go.

Comment: @Flimzy this is my body data ->  let data = {
        "user": user,
        "password": password
    }

Comment: Sending it as is is throwing 403, but stringifying it and sending is working

Comment: If you want to consume JSON you must send JSON. I have no idea how Node serializes an arbitrary object. So: Simply send JSON (and not random garbage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sending JSON to any http server you always have to use `JSON.stringify()`.

Not doing so will result in sending `[object Object]`... 
There are client libraries that do this kind of heavy lifting for you, but behind the scenes the JSON is always send as a string.

---

Node.JS handles it the same way... it receives the string representation and usually something like body parser is run on the incoming request to extract the JSON from the string. So it might happen here behind the scenes, but it still happens.